# What is curve fitting and how do I fit a curve?

Tags: geometry

I want to understand the concept. What material could I read to learn about it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve-fitting

Comment: How about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting  or  http://lifesun.info/what-is-curve-fitting/

Comment: @vadim123  Hey, when I was googling on wikepedia, I thought I saw your shadow...:)

Comment: @vadim123 and imranfat Maybe Marcio didn't really understand the Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcio, here is a simple try before you go into all sorts of scientific stories.
Let's fit a "curve" called a line through two given points: (1,1) and (2,2)
Perhaps you realize that the best line is y = x right? It's the best fit.
Now there is a third point coming in: (4,5) Obviously there is no single line passing through all three points. The question then becomes: Is there a line that "deviates the least" from these three points? In other words, can you construct a line that passes these three points "as close as" possible? It is almost like a game who can draw such a line the best. This is in lay man's terms "curve fitting", because the scenario I described with a line and three points, can be extended to a polynomial with many points...

Comment: And in the scenario, the curve is a line, right?

Comment: @BCLC yes it is, but generally it doesn't have to be a line.

Comment: Is fitting a line equivalent to linear regression?

Comment: @BCLC read this: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/curve-fitting-with-linear-and-nonlinear-regression

Comment: @imranfant Skimming suggests the answer is yes. :))

Comment: @imranfant Wiki says that "A related topic is regression analysis" so I was just wondering if they were exactly the same like maybe linear regression was a subset or an extension of line fitting.

Comment: @BCLC Linear regression is line fitting and the formula to find the line's slope and y-intercept can be found in elementary stats books. Please note that the average of all x-values and average of all y- values form a point through which this line always passes

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with geometry. Curve fitting is creating a curve (e.g. a line) that best describes a certain set of data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting

Like here:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Regression_circulaire_coope_arc_de_cercle.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRegression_circulaire_coope_arc_de_cercle.svg)

You might want to check out linear regression (curve in question is a line). Ch11 I think here: http://ihmsi.org/upload/Richard%20J.%20Larsen%20-%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Mathematical%20Statistics%20and%20Its%20Applications%20-%205th%20Edition.pdf

Or for other curves: http://kau.edu.sa/GetFile.aspx?id=188051&fn=Larson%20-%20Edwards%20y%20Falvo%20Elementary%20Linear%20Algebra.pdf